# Angular - Get undefined from service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

**logdetay.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Logdetay } from './logdetay.model';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogdetayService {

  formData:Logdetay={
    Message: null,
    CreateDate: null,
    LogType: null,
    Int: null


  };

  readonly rootUrl='https://localhost:44370/api';
  list : Logdetay[];
  constructor(private httpclient:HttpClient) { }

  postlogDetay(formData:Logdetay){
    return this.httpclient.post(this.rootUrl+'/Logtbs',formData);

  }
  refreshList()
  {
    this.httpclient.get(this.rootUrl + '/Logtbs')
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => this.list = res as Logdetay[]);   
  }
}
```

---

**logdetay-liste.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
      <td >{{pd.Message}}</td>
      <td >{{pd.Logtype}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**logdetay-liste.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Logdetay } from 'src/app/paylas/logdetay.model';
import { LogdetayService } from 'src/app/paylas/logdetay.service';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logdetay-liste',
  templateUrl: './logdetay-liste.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class LogdetayListeComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private service : LogdetayService) {  }
  ngOnInit() {

     this.service.refreshList();



  }


}
```

---

**Output:**
`this.service.refreshList();` in logdetay-list.component.ts value comes `undefined`.

I am trying to get information via web API. I was able to do the insertion.
How can I show the values ​​on the page?

Comment: `constructor(private service : LogdetayService)` `service` variable is `private`. Might be error here. Can you try passing it to a public variable?

Comment: I made it public. it didn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue(s)

**Issue 1**:

As @Tonbul mentioned in the comment, you are **accessing the `service`** in the HTML component which **it was a `private` variable**.

```
<tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
  ...
</tr>
```

**Issue 2**:

You are **accessing the `list` from `LogdetayService` which is `private`**. By default, a variable without specifying any accessing type will be set to `private`.

```js
export class LogdetayService {
    list : Logdetay[];

    ...
}
```

---

### Solution(s)

**Solution 1: Declare variables as `public`**

**1.1** Set `service` as `public`

> logdetay-liste.component.ts

```js
export class LogdetayListeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public service : LogdetayService) {  }
}
```

**1.2** Set `list` as `public`

> logdetay.service.ts

```js
export class LogdetayService {
    public list : Logdetay[];

    ...
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkeuyd)

---

**Solution 2: Return result as `Observable<Logdetay[]>`**

**2.1** Return as `Observable<Logdetay[]>`

> logdetay.service.ts

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class LogdetayService {

refreshList(): Observable<Logdetay[]> {
    return this.httpclient
       .get<Logdetay[]>(this.rootUrl + '/Logtbs');
  }
}
```

**2.2** Declare `list` variable  and assign value in `subscribe event` from `Observable`

> logdetay-liste.component.ts

```js
import { Logdetay } from '../paylas/logdetay.model';

export class LogdetayListeComponent implements OnInit {
  list: Logdetay[];

  constructor(private service: LogdetayService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.refreshList().subscribe(res => (this.list = res));
  }
}
```

**2.3** Replace `service.list` with `list`

> logdetay-liste.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let pd of list">
    ...
</tr>
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gzvuez)